# Recursively copy a file to the consequtive directory in a list while executing a job

Tags: python, loops, recursion, directory, copy

I have a list of directories where some jobs are executed. I wanted to execute the first job and copy it to the next directory as an input and execute the job. I need to continue this through the loop. How do I go about doing this. For example I have a python code posted here which recursively loops through the directories and execute the job. How do I modify this code if possible?

```
import os
import re
import shutil
import subprocess
import shlex

basedir = os.path.join('/scratch', 'run')
#These are my job directories
aoa=['08deg','09deg','10deg']

# I loop over my directory list and execute the job
for x in range(len(aoa)):
    path=os.path.join(basedir,aoa[x])
    os.chdir(path)
    print("Current working directory: {0}".format(os.getcwd()))
    #This is the job I need to run
    os.system(" time mpirun -np 1008 SU2_CFD turb_low_cfl.cfg | tee restart.dat")
    #I need to copy the output restart.dat to the consecutive directory and repeat this process
```

Comment: What is restart.dat? In what way, if any, does the current code not work?

Comment: It is an output/input of the code. The current code does not have the capacity to recursively copy the output/input to the consequent folder. The code execution is as follows. 1. You execute the code in the 08deg folder. You get the output file restart.dat 2. You copy this to 09deg folder execute the code and get restart.dat which needs to be copied to the 10deg folder and the process repeats. I hope it is clear.

Comment: Just modified the code so that it is more understandable

Comment: I'm not really sure why you need to copy the file into different folders? Won't the command just overwrite it? Or are you trying to merge the files together?

Comment: No, the command takes the output of the previous directory run as an input to the current directory and runs the job. It is similar to that of a recurrent neural network where the output of the previous step is the input of the current step. The output of the current step is the input of the next step.  Here step means the job execution in the different directories (although it is same and repetative)

Comment: The first directory is of course the starting point and need not be initialised from any solutions from the previous directories